# Using HTML 5 / Javascript template to send contact e-mail form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I recently created a simple site for a friend's business using an HTML 5 template. It contained some cutesy Javascript elements too. The website URL is [www.michianamemories.com](http://www.michianamemories.com)

One of the elements is a Contact Form at the bottom of the page. It looks like the "Send Message" button is coded to do absolutely nothing. How simple is it to have this form forward the user-entered values (ie: their name, e-mail, and their message) to a dedicated e-mail inbox?

If it's not that simple, what other options are available to make the form functional but also integrated with the site's general theme?

I'm assuming the answer is very simple, but I'm a novice at HTML 5 and am totally clueless about Javascript. Your help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Did you mean JavaScript instead of Java? The two are _very_ different.

Comment: @MattBall Ah, yes. My lack of knowledge is showing all ready. Edited in the original post.

Comment: Voting to close because the answer’s simply: You can’t send e-mail with only JavaScript on the client side. Slightly-longer explanation is just that you either need your own server backend of some kind to handle taking the message & sending it as SMTP e-mail, or else you use some third-party service for doing it (if such exist). Beyond that the possible “answers” here for the available options are infinite & choosing among them is primarily opinion-based—so it’s not productive to keep this open.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in pure Javascript. Sending email requires server-side processing.

There are several websites that will let you generate simple email forms, check out: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=email+form+generator&aq=5&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=email+form

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't allow you to submit a form to an email.

You could use `mailto` but it's not the friendliest piece of functionality. It will open up Outlook and dump the form data into the email content. Has a lot of issues though.

[More info on mailto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)

My recommendation is to use a "form mail script". This is only done on server side though so you'll need to have a web server. You'll need to google and read up on them.

[Reference about form submit options](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/html-email-form.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best thing you can do is to create a simple Back-End App in PHP.

1. Create file `mail.php` in your root directory.
2. In your HTML `form` tag you need to add  the `action` attribute with the path to `mail.php` file and the `method` attribute, so that the form knows which HTTP Request Method use to send the data `<form action="mail.php" method ="post">`. This will add the action to trigger for the 'Send Message' button, that you said is not working.

   *This happens because now the button knows what to do if you click it. It takes all of your data from the form input fields and send them to the `mail.php` file. This file needs to fetch them and validate them. (You should at least create the validation for the required fields in your form, to check if they're not null. You can make some extra validations in your build-in html attributes or with some help of the JavaScript)*
3. The most important thing now, is to create the Mail function in your `mail.php`. Here is all the documentation you need to do this: [PHP Mail Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Here is the code (your site is not working so I'm just improvising with the input fields):

HTML:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">

    <label for="name-field">Name:</label>
    <input id="name-field" name="name" type="text" required>

    <label for="surname-field">Surname:</label>
    <input id="surname-field" name="surname" type="text" required>

    <label for="message-field">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message-field" name="message" required></textarea>

    <label for="mail-field">Your e-mail:</label>
    <input id="mail-field" name="mail" type="mail" required>

    <button type="submit">Send Message</button>

</form>
```

PHP:

```
// Validating if everything is filled
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['mail'])
{
    $to = "example@mysite.com";
    $subject = "Automatically generated messege from" . $_POST['name'] . ' ' . $_POST['surname'];
    $body = $_POST['message'];
    $headers = 'To: ' . $to . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['mail'];

    // Send mail function
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
    { 
        echo 'Mail sent successfuly!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error occurred while sending the message';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can't use HTML5 to send e-mail. This needs to be done on your server.

One easy and free solution is to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) though. You can [publish your Apps Script as a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and have a `doPost` method like this:

```
function doPost(e){
    var email = e.parameter.email;
    var subject = 'E-mail from website';
    var message = e.parameter.message;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

    return ContentService.createTextOutput('E-mail sent!');
}
```

And in your HTML, you would have a form like this:

```
<form action="url to your deployed app script" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email"></input>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

The URL to put in the `action` attribute will be shown when you [deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) your Apps Script as a Web App:

[image: Deploy as web app screenshot]